# Is there a consistent way to test for 0 (zero) when using BCMath?

Tags: php, bcmath

Running the following, I would expect to receive `N, Y, Y`.

I understand why I'm not, because `'0.00' != '0'` for the second example, but is there a consistent way of testing for `0` without casting back to a float/double, and without dropping the `===` to a `==`.

```
echo bcmul( '5.1', '2.234', 2 );
echo bcmul( '5.1', '2.234', 2 ) === '0' ? '  Y  ' : '  N  ';
echo "<br/>";

echo bcmul( '0.00', '000.00', 2 );
echo bcmul( '0.00', '000.00', 2 ) === '0' ? '  Y  ' : '  N  ';
echo "<br/>";

echo bcmul( '0', '0', 2 );
echo bcmul( '0', '0', 2 ) === '0' ? '  Y  ' : '  N  ';
echo "<br/>";
```

---

**Notes**

> Why don't I want to drop the `===`?

If I'm providing out functionality as part of a grander project, via a method such as `get_total_cost()`, I don't feel that it's intuitive to other developers to have to drop the strict comparison, when they are expecting the function to return a numeric value as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A. Yes `0.00 !== 0` is valid because they are not the same type

```
var_dump(0.00,0);
```

Output

```
float 0
int 0
```

B. `0 !== "0"` is valid because they are not the same type

```
var_dump(0,"0");
```

Output

```
int 0
string '0' (length=1)
```

C. Why don't I want to drop the `===`

```
var_dump("hello" == 0 );  true
var_dump("hello" === 0 );  false
```

[Conclusion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

> $a === $b TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.

I guess this is what you want

```
echo (int) bcmul('0.00', '000.00', 2) === (int) '0' ? '  Y  ' : '  N  '; 
       ^                                    ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 8.0 you could use `bccomp()` to compare two BC numbers. For example:

```
$equals = (bccomp("0.00", "0") === 0);
```

The result of the function will be the integer 0 if they are equal, 1 if the first is greater than the second, and -1 if the second is greater than the first.

Be aware that the third parameter is the precision at which the comparison will be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [ctype_digit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) to determine if the returned string contains a "clean" int, or if it contains a floating point dot somewhere, and then just have two sets of Y/N functions; One for string-ints and one for string-floats.